# jQuery: How can I get a click event to trigger for all elements with identical IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery `click` event that needs to trigger for any element clicked on with a given ID.

[Link to jsfiddle demo here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Miega/ahkgktrm/1/)

The function in question:

```
$("#trigger").click(function(e) {
  console.log($(this)[0].title);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

My function only works on the ***very first*** element with the `trigger` ID, but none of the others. **How can I get my function to work on all of those elements?**

Comment: [Use classes instead](https://jsfiddle.net/ahkgktrm/2/)

Comment: Technically, to answer your question, you *can* use the attribute selector `$("[id=trigger]")`, **but it's very frowned upon to have duplicate IDs**. Just use classes.

Comment: Well, ids are supposed to be unique, you should consider using classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per specification, ID's must be unique to a single element. With that specification, JQuery will action upon the first element it finds with that ID then complete.

Classes on the other hand can be shared among elements. You would need to modify your elements to have unique IDs (or none at all) so you have a valid html then add the class "trigger" (or whatever) to your targeted elements. You would then update your JS like so:

```js
$(".trigger").click(function(e) {
  console.log(this.title);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trigger" title="One">Hello</div>
<div class="trigger" title="Two">Hello</div>
<div class="trigger" title="Three">Hello</div>
```

Notice the only change is using "." instead of "#" . This tells jquery to select by class instead of ID.

Comment: @Thassa updated for clearer explanation. If this works then please don't forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is redundant, just use `this`

Comment: @UlysseBN thanks for the catch, I went straight to modify the class selector and glossed over the function when I copied/pasted the user's example.